# Is it possible to draw sparklines (Trend graphs) in Excel Through OpenXML/ClosedXML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, closedxml

I'm trying to draw a sparklines in Excel through C# application, but I couldn't find any code documentation/samples to draw sparklines in Excel, I checked the OpenXML/ClosedXML SDks.

Please provide any references of documentation or code snippets for this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it is possible with Open XML.  Almost all parts of an Excel file, can be reverse engineered into C# code using the Open XML Productivity Tool.  I just did a simple Sparkline example and have generated the the below Excel file using C#:

[[image]]

Follow these steps:

1. [Install Open XML SDK with the Productivity Tool](https://blog.followyourshot.com/downloading-installing-and-running-the-openxml-productivity-tool/)
2. Generate an Excel file with Sparklines for your particular project needs.
3. Open the file inside the Open XML Productivity Tool.
4. Select the base element in the file and Click the **Reflect Code** button and it will generate the C# code for you in the right hand pane.

Since you are the C# developer, you will then need to make the appropriate changes the code to fit the needs of your product/solution.

[I have posted the code that generated the above sparkline to GitHub](https://github.com/thomasbtatum/GenerateAnyExcelFileWithCSharp/tree/sparkline-so42533244).  Feel free to download it and run it.  It is a simple one button WPF and will save it to the file name you specify.

Comment: Thank you Taterhead